# Differential pair for Ethernet on Olimex boards

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, ethernet, esp32, impedance-matching

Just out of curiosity I was looking into ESP32 based boards such as EVA, GATEWAY, POE, POE-ISO by Olimex and found the differential pair used for Ethernet is all different sizes (i.e.: width and space between them) even though the board thickness is 1.6 mm for all.

So with an assumption that H (height of dielectric between two layers) will be 0.48 mm (normally) I tried calculating the Zdiff for these tracks which is surprisingly coming around 130 ohm which is way way off from what it should be (100 ohm).

Does anyone have any explanation why its done this way?

Comment: Please show your calculations and measurements.

Comment: If you assume the thickness between layers wrong, then you assume wrong impedance. They all might all add up to 1.6mm but there may be differences in the thickness between layers. Or, if your measurements are correct, then they might have incorrect trace impedance.

Comment: What speed Ethernet?  And how long are these traces?